# Can't Source vimrc file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to learn vim right now and I was trying to source vimrc for the first time. After editing the file I used the command:

```
:so %
```

But I got the error:

`Can't open file /c/Users/Name/.vimrc`

I also tried using:

```
:so $HOME/.vimrc
```

But got the same error. How do I source my .vimrc file

Answer (score 1):

have you saved the file before trying to source it(`:w`)?